# dart as server web application or golang

Tags: go, dart

I am planing to write an social network application and thinking about to use dart on backend. But I am asking me, if dart would be the right choice for backend application. I was searching in internet about this topic, but could not find something useful, that convince me to use dart for backend.

I am thinking to use golang, but I have to learn this language from zero. In dart I have some experience and really like dart language.

You know, I try make the right choice to use right tools, so I need some suggestions? Dart or golang?

I know, that java provide me hug ecosystem, but i don't like to learn java at all, just don't like java.

I would choose neo4j database, i am pretty sure, this suits for social network.

Comment: I just want you make aware that such questions are highly opinionated and therefore discouraged on StackOverflow. See the help menu above about topics `how to add good questions` and so on.

Comment: It's not just the language, but also the tooling around it. I don't know anything about Dart, so I can only say what I like about Go: easy to deploy (just build a binary, no external dependencies), good testing environment, nice web frameworks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't like Java very much and developed a server in Go. I enjoyed working with Go a lot. Then I started with the client and because I also don't like JavaScript (in fact I hate it) I went with Dart which I like a lot. I already did a lot of server side work in Dart. A big advantage is that I can share code between client and sever, which is actually a lot in my current project.

I like Go better for server side development but I will stick with Dart for projects where I already use Dart for the client. It's just too difficult and time-consuming to stay up-to-date on two different languages (and ecosystem and libraries) for such new and fast evolving languages.

I think each language is a very good fit for this Job. Java has an awful lot of existing libs, tutorials, ... but most of the important things are covered in Go and Dart as well.

Basically I would say, stick with the language you know best. Learning a new language will impede your productivity for several months at least.

Comment: On other side, i think, that dart team will be more in the future work on frontend then in backend. That dart team enforce development on frontend more than on backend?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that. The browser is the more difficult part. JavaScript has a monopoly here and they need to break this down and need to convince other browser vendors to support Dart, therefore this needs to be a very convincing story. On the server side this is much easier. When Dart is used on the client many will choose it for the server as well (as argued above) this is the reason why Node.js exists at all (IMHO). Dart on the server works quite well already, but there are still a lot of issues to fix on the client. It is just so awfully hard not at last to support all browsers.

Comment: Dart team invest a lot of time on frontend development, so maybe they will forget to develop for backend stuff. Does go support non-blocking I/O too?

Comment: AppEngine support is currently work-in-progress. Support for `pub global`, `pub run` (only relevant to the server/console) was added very recently. I think Dart is already working quite well on the server and I can't comprehend your fear. It's just that currently the client side lacks some substantial parts to ensure Darts success (Angular and Polymer are not even beta) while on the server lacking parts are mostly about improving the usability/developer experience.

Comment: How is the performance between golang and dart? And of course ecosystem too.

Comment: Performance is 'excellent' with Go and 'good' with Dart. I know this doesn't say much but you can expect Go to be notable faster. But even when performance is **very** important to you, it should be much more important how fast you will get the solution out there. A mediocre fast available solution is infinite better as an incredible fast application that never hit the market. Most of the time 99% of your code is fast enough but there are just some hot spots (1%) that need to be optimized. Your app should run stable before you start analyzing which code belongs to the 1% and needs optimization

Comment: Conclusion, dart for backend usage would be a good choice?

Comment: Conclusion: It depends on your preferences. (This is why your question is not a good fit for StackOverflow. There are none **and** infinite correct answers for this question.)

Comment: what do you recommended for me, you as expert for both technology for develop a social network or what would you choose, when you have a choice.

Comment: I would suggest you go with Dart. You know it already. Go is notable different (no classes, libraries, concurrent programming, ...).

Comment: Go doesn't use an async model in the same way as Dart. Dart even needs to state in the docs that because it is a single threaded async event model, code needs to be careful never to block. In Go, you have goroutines that can run concurrently. Generally the model you will see is that you can write your code in a way that looks synchronous but runs concurrently.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer go community seems to be more active then dart server right? I discover this link github.com/avelino/awesome-go#web-frameworks. Go provide a lot of webframework in comparing to dart.

Comment: The Go community is more vibrant than Darts. One of the reasons is IMHO, that Go is available about a year longer than Dart. Because Go is generating HTML/JavaScript for the client which is more difficult than how it's done in SPA with Dart there are more different attempts to solve this. I think many of these web frameworks are redundant when you use Dart on the client. Go is clearly the better language/ecosystem in comparsion to Dart when you look at the server alone. But when you develop the client in Dart, other arguments become more important (as argued above) - just my opinion

Comment: yes of course, i would develop frontend in dart but for server i would use go. On client, I would use the combination angulardart with polymer. About my social network, it would calculate a lot of image stuff. Conclusion: For server i golang to use golang for frontend dart, right?

Comment: @jdi I haven't found a way to block in Dart yet. This is the advantage of the async model. When there can never be two threads to access a resource concurrently you never need to lock.

Answer (score 0):

If you design your application in terms of loosely coupled modules then you can write(prototype) modules in Dart and if one day you will need to re-implement some of them in GO (for example you need better performance) it will be doable. Look at [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)
Also it will make your application scalable and you will be able to expose API for separate modules (for example, if you need some of them as a phone app back-end or for the 3-d party developers)